# Calling `shared_ptr.get()` vs copy-initialization, what's the difference?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

first version print use_count = 2;

```
shared_ptr<int> s{make_shared<int>(15)};
  auto b = s;
  cout<<s.use_count()<<endl;
  auto c = s.get();
  cout<<s.use_count()<<endl;
  cout<<*c<<endl;
```

---

second version use_count = 3;

```
shared_ptr<int> s{make_shared<int>(15)};
  auto b = s;
  cout<<s.use_count()<<endl;
  auto c = s;
  cout<<s.use_count()<<endl;
  cout<<*c<<endl;
```

---

**Question:**

- Why is the behavior different between the two versions?

Comment: don't use `shared_ptr<>`. unless your object has no (logical) owner.

Answer (score 1):

#### Introduction

Every time you make a copy of a *shared_ptr* the *use-count* is increased since you then have an additional handle to the underlying resource being tracked.

In order to obtain the value of the underlying pointer, *shared_ptr* has a member-function named `get`. This function will return the address of the tracked resource, it will **not** create an additional *shared_ptr* tracking the same pointer.

---

#### Potential dangers

In your first snippet you effectively have 2 instances of *shared_ptr* that refers to the same resource, but in the latter you have three.

The difference being;

- `auto a = s` will create a copy of `s`, and the type of `a` is that of `s` (a *shared_ptr*)
- `auto b = s.get ()` will initialize `b` with the address of the tracked resource managed by `s`, hence it will be a *raw-pointer*.

---

If you don't know exactly what you are doing, calling `.get ()` might be dangerous, as can be seen in the following snippet.

```
int * ptr = nullptr;

{
  std::shared_ptr<int> sp { make_shared<int> (15) };
  ptr = sp.get ();
}

std::cout << *ptr << std::endl; // (A), dangling pointer
```

Inside our nested scope we create a *shared_ptr* named `sp`, and we ask it to keep track of an `int` with *dynamic storage duration* created from our call to `make_shared`.

We obtain the address of this `int` by calling `sp.get ()`, and assign it to `ptr`.

When the scope of `sp` ends, `sp` will release the resource managed since there's no more *shared_ptr*s that refers to it.

By trying to print the value of `*ptr` we are invoking *undefined behavior* in (*A*) since the value isn't available, it was destroyed with the destruction of `sp`.